# jQuery Shutter occupying all the document (Camera Effect)

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this example for getting a Camera Shutter Effect: [Click Here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/photography-portfolio-shutter-effect/)

So, I need this effect occupying all the document (width: 100% and height: 100%), but, how to i've to do?

Because if I set `var container = $('body');` the effect does not occupy all the window. So, what I've to do? larger image?

Comment: The code in your JSFiddle doesn't actually work.

Comment: When I press "Shutter" nothing happens. Just checked in FF, IE, and Chrome.

Comment: You are following the ["Shutter Effect with Canvas and jQuery"](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/photography-portfolio-shutter-effect/). The plugin calculates the position of each leaf in the shutter, assuming that the dimensions of the container is fixed, so simply blowing up the container isn't enough. You have to adjust the width/height values in the plugin script as well.

Comment: @user880772 Yes, i'm following this tutorial... But, i'm beginner and i don't know where change the values in the plugin for him occupy all the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your body's height does not cover the entire page, you should add `height: 100%;` in html tag like below:

```
html{
    background:url('../img/bg_tile.jpg') repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But here comes another issue, this plugin draws the canvas depends on the object's height. So you can see this two images(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBZx.png,   https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8DWM.png) I tested in browser with different width.

I think the effect is not you want. And I think this can be re-written with CSS3, this canvas plugin may speed down when the size is large.

To solve this problem, I edited `jquery.shutter.js` to let the canvas size equals to body size, and resize the image(shutter.png) to 2x as below:

LINE 37:

```
var frames = {num:15, height:element.height(), width:element.width()},
```

LINE 128:

```
c.drawImage(img,-slices.width,-(frames.height/2 + offset), 416*2, 500*2);
```

**Entire jquery.shutter.js:**

```
(function(){ 

    // Creating a regular jQuery plugin:

    $.fn.tzShutter = function(options){

        // Checking for canvas support. Works in all modern browsers:
        var supportsCanvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

        // Providing default values:

        options = $.extend({
            openCallback:function(){},
            closeCallback:function(){},
            loadCompleteCallback:function(){},
            hideWhenOpened:true,
            imgSrc: 'jquery.shutter/shutter.png'
        },options);

        var element = this;

        if(!supportsCanvas){

            // If there is no support for canvas, bind the
            // callack functions straight away and exit:

            element.bind('shutterOpen',options.openCallback)
                   .bind('shutterClose',options.closeCallback);

            options.loadCompleteCallback();

            return element;
        }

        window.setTimeout(function(){

            var frames = {num:15, height:element.height(), width:element.width()},
                slices = {num:8, width: 416, height:500, startDeg:30},
                animation = {
                    width : element.width(),
                    height : element.height(),
                    offsetTop: (frames.height-element.height())/2
                },

                // This will calculate the rotate difference between the
                // slices of the shutter. (2*Math.PI equals 360 degrees in radians):

                rotateStep = 2*Math.PI/slices.num, 
                rotateDeg = 30;

            // Calculating the offset           
            slices.angleStep = ((90 - slices.startDeg)/frames.num)*Math.PI/180;

            // The shutter slice image:
            var img = new Image();

            // Defining the callback before setting the source of the image:
            img.onload = function(){

                window.console && console.time && console.time("Generating Frames");

                // The film div holds 15 canvas elements (or frames).

                var film = $('<div>',{
                    className: 'film',
                    css:{
                        height: frames.num*frames.height,
                        width: frames.width,
                        marginLeft: -frames.width/2, // Centering horizontally
                        top: -animation.offsetTop
                    }
                });

                // The animation holder hides the film with overflow:hidden,
                // exposing only one frame at a time.

                var animationHolder = $('<div>',{
                    className: 'shutterAnimationHolder',
                    css:{
                        width:animation.width,
                        height:animation.height
                    }
                });

                for(var z=0;z<frames.num;z++){

                    // Creating 15 canvas elements.

                    var canvas  = document.createElement('canvas'),
                        c       = canvas.getContext("2d");

                    canvas.width=frames.width;
                    canvas.height=frames.height;

                    c.translate(frames.width/2,frames.height/2);

                    for(var i=0;i<slices.num;i++){

                        // For each canvas, generate the different
                        // states of the shutter by drawing the shutter
                        // slices with a different rotation difference.

                        // Rotating the canvas with the step, so we can
                        // paint the different slices of the shutter.
                        c.rotate(-rotateStep);

                        // Saving the current rotation settings, so we can easily revert
                        // back to them after applying an additional rotation to the slice.

                        c.save();

                        // Moving the origin point (around which we are rotating
                        // the canvas) to the bottom-center of the shutter slice.
                        c.translate(0,frames.height/2);

                        // This rotation determines how widely the shutter is opened.
                        c.rotate((frames.num-1-z)*slices.angleStep);

                        // An additional offset, applied to the last five frames,
                        // so we get a smoother animation:

                        var offset = 0;
                        if((frames.num-1-z) <5){
                            offset = (frames.num-1-z)*5;
                        }

                        // Drawing the shutter image
                        c.drawImage(img,-slices.width,-(frames.height/2 + offset), 416*2, 500*2);

                        // Reverting back to the saved settings above.
                        c.restore();
                    }

                    // Adding the canvas (or frame) to the film div.
                    film.append(canvas);
                }

                // Appending the film to the animation holder.
                animationHolder.append(film);

                if(options.hideWhenOpened){
                    animationHolder.hide();
                }

                element.css('position','relative').append(animationHolder);

                var animating = false;

                // Binding custom open and close events, which trigger
                // the shutter animations.

                element.bind('shutterClose',function(){

                    if(animating) return false;
                    animating = true;

                    var count = 0;

                    var close = function(){

                        (function animate(){
                            if(count>=frames.num){
                                animating=false;

                                // Calling the user provided callback.
                                options.closeCallback.call(element);

                                return false;
                            }

                            film.css('top',-frames.height*count - animation.offsetTop);
                            count++;
                            setTimeout(animate,20);
                        })();
                    }

                    if(options.hideWhenOpened){
                        animationHolder.fadeIn(60,close);
                    }
                    else close();
                });

                element.bind('shutterOpen',function(){

                    if(animating) return false;
                    animating = true;

                    var count = frames.num-1;

                    (function animate(){
                        if(count<0){

                            var hide = function(){
                                animating=false;
                                // Calling the user supplied callback:
                                options.openCallback.call(element);
                            };

                            if(options.hideWhenOpened){
                                animationHolder.fadeOut(60,hide);
                            }
                            else{
                                hide();
                            }

                            return false;
                        }

                        film.css('top',-frames.height*count - animation.offsetTop);
                        count--;

                        setTimeout(animate,20);
                    })();
                });

                // Writing the timing information if the
                // firebug/web development console is opened:

                window.console && console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd("Generating Frames");
                options.loadCompleteCallback();
            };

            img.src = options.imgSrc;

        },0);

        return element;     
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working with all height now, but, and the width? If you see the link page, the width not occupy all the document...